# List or Array of String Contain specific word in Html Source Code

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, web

I want to develop a program which can count the html tags in source code, so i write a code for fetching source code of site like this.

```
WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
req.Method = "GET";
string source;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
{
    source = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

with this way i can fetch the source code of site and binding to string.
Next what i want is controlling the string and counting
`html` `/html` `body` `/body` `p` `/p` bla bla bla.
What is the LINQ way of counting all html tags in source and showing results like

> HTML: 2
>
> BODY:2
>
> UL:42

Comment: Can you share what you have already tried and what the results were?

Answer (score 3):

You ca use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML and to count all tags recursively:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(source);
int allTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Count();
```

If you want to count only specific tags(f.e. `UL`) change `Descendants` to `Descendants("UL")`.

Note that this is counted as one UL-tag (not two):

```
   <ul>
      <li><a id=""menuSubItem1""></a></li>
      <li><a id=""menuSubItem2""></a></li>
   </ul>
```

You can also use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse html directly from web:

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://google.com");
int countAll = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Count();
int countHtml = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("HTML").Count();
int countBody = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("BODY").Count();
int countUL = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("UL").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend HtmlAgilityPack

```
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(source);
var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
            .Descendants()
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count() * 2);
```

This way you can group all tags by their name easily, and get the count of a particular node using `nodes["html"]` for example.

`Descendants` will also return text nodes, the text between tags are counted as one node.It will also include the comments.If you want to get *only* element nodes you can add:

```
.Where(x => x.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
```

Before `GroupBy`.